# What is wrong with the sum function in this query?

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
SELECT *
FROM
    Open_Credit_Detail, closed_Credit_Detail, Credit_Consumer_Details, CONSUMER
WHERE 
    sum(Open_Credit_Detail.AMT_OF_INSTALMENT) > 1000 
    AND sum(Open_Credit_Detail.DAYS_DUE) >= 30 
    AND sum(Open_Credit_Detail.OVERDUE_AMOUNT) = 1000 
    AND sum(Open_Credit_Detail.APPROVAL_AMOUNT) >= 25000 
    AND sum(Credit_Consumer_Details.loan_no) >= 1 
    AND Sum(closed_Credit_Detail.AMT_OF_INSTALMENT) >= 1000 
    AND sum(closed_Credit_Detail.DAYS_DUE) >= 30
```

Comment: Your query has numerous problem.  I would start with a simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: the error is near sum operator
Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs - that old-style comma-](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) separated list of tables style was replaced with the proper ANSI JOIN syntax in the ANSI-92 SQL Standard (more than 20 years ago) and its use is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds and looks like you are trying to use an invalid datatype for the sum function. From looking at the code i don't fully understand why you are using a sum function for checking a value against another. I would post the question again with some information on what you are trying to do. A look at the database tables would also be very helpful to anyone that is trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM Open_Credit_Detail , closed_Credit_Detail , Credit_Consumer_Details , CONSUMER WHERE (sum(Open_Credit_Detail.AMT_OF_INSTALMENT) > 1000 ) AND( sum(Open_Credit_Detail.DAYS_DUE) >= 30 ) AND (sum(Open_Credit_Detail.OVERDUE_AMOUNT) = 1000 ) AND (sum(Open_Credit_Detail.APPROVAL_AMOUNT) >= 25000 ) AND( sum(Credit_Consumer_Details.loan_no) >= 1 ) AND( sum(closed_Credit_Detail.AMT_OF_INSTALMENT) >= 1000 ) AND(sum(closed_Credit_Detail.DAYS_DUE) >= 30)

Comment: Try this query.if its not working. Still there exist an error .Giver your table structure with sample values .so that is very easy to help u

Comment: Sorry it has the same problem

Comment: Try HAVING  clause instead of where